# Adding a Dapper Dynamic Output Parameter in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, parameters, .net-4.0, dapper

I'm trying to use Dapper to call a stored procedure that has a couple Output parameters, using VB.NET (and .NET 4.0).

However, it seems I cannot use the `DynamicParameters.Add` method, because I'm getting the following compiler error:

> 'Add' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name
>   exist in class 'Dapper.DynamicParameters'.

...when I try to write the following line:

```
p.Add("@NewRecordID", DbType:=DbType.Int32, direction:=ParameterDirection.Output)
```

A quick search tells me this sometimes happens when using a C# library that has multiple methods that differ only in name case (VB.NET being case-insensitive).  Searching the Dapper source code for `DynamicParameters` does show the following two overloads for the `Add` method, but they both use the same case, and the compiler should be able to discern between the two.

```
public void Add(string name, object value, DbType? dbType, ParameterDirection? direction, int? size)

public void Add(string name, object value = null, DbType? dbType = null, ParameterDirection? direction = null, int? size = null, byte? precision = null, byte? scale = null)
```

(I've also tried adding `scale:=Nothing` to the call to force the second overload, to no avail.)

While I can work around this with the input parameters by passing in an anonymous object to the `DynamicParameters` constructor, I can't find a way around this when adding the output parameters.

I've checked the project references to ensure there aren't multiple or ambiguous assembly references.

Has anybody encountered this problem before, and found a workaround?

At the moment, the only option I can think of is to re-write the stored procedure call without using Dapper, [as implied here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235408(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: I suspect the ambiguity involves the optional parameters in the Add methods, which would mean the only resolution would be to change the signature of the Dapper methods.

Comment: Ooh, that's nasty. Unfortunately, the twin overload above is typical of adding optional parameters in a v2 api by making the old call have all non-optional parameters.

Comment: Can you try `p.Add("@NewRecordID", Nothing, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output, Nothing)` ?

Comment: Tried, with the same result, even if I go so far as `p.Add("@NewRecordID", Nothing, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)`.

Comment: am I allowed to shout and scream "curse you VB!!!" ?

Comment: There's nothing in here that shouts "this won't work" - I am genuinely surprised that VB is upset by this overload - surprised and confused :'(

Comment: Yes, you can shout and scream, and I believe the problem goes away for VB in .NET 4.5.  In my case, though, I have a way of getting the information I need from the stored proc results, bypassing the output parameter, so I can still use Dapper for this database call without calling `DynamicParameters.Add`.

Comment: I should also add that the `.Add` method doesn't even show up in IntelliSense, so I suspect it's something deeper than the compiler not being able to pick the appropriate overload.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, the following are all potential solutions:

1. Rewrite the Stored Procedure to not use Output parameters.  (The option I was able to use in this case.)
2. Rewrite the code calling the Stored Procedure to use standard ADO.NET.
3. Rewrite Dapper to use a different overload pattern for `DynamicParameters.Add`.
4. Update the project to use .NET 4.5.
5. Reimplement IDynamicParameter(s) or possibly subclass DynamicParameters

Comment: 5. Reimplement IDynamicParameter(s) or possibly subclass DynamicParameters?

Comment: Good idea, added to the list.